# psycopg2 to deal with timestamp without time zone

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, psycopg2

I obtain a record from PostgreSQL, which its type is `timestamp without time zone`

I am using psycopg2

I might get `datetime` object if I am using `timestamp with time zone`. But, currently, this is not the case.
http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#time-zones-handling

I realize I am getting float type instead.

How can I suppose to get value like from the given float?

```
Jan 07, 2010
16:38:49
```

---

```
    connection.cursor.execute(sql, data)
    records = connection.cursor.fetchall()

    # In PostgreSQL, type is "timestamp without time zone"

    # <type 'float'>
    print type(record['_start_timestamp'])
    # 1.28946608161e+12
    print record['_start_timestamp']
    # TypeError: argument must be 9-item sequence, not float
    print time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", record['_start_timestamp'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The float value that you're getting seems to be milliseconds from the epoch.  So this seems to give what you're looking for:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from datetime import datetime
import time

your_time = 1.28946608161e+12

print time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000",
                    datetime.fromtimestamp(your_time/1000).timetuple()
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for newer people. As of at least psycopg2 2.7.1, the "timestamp without time zone" returns a datetime.

So `your_time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000")` now will just work.