# Python- postgresql timestamp and time without time zone

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, timestamp

I have 2 strings which represent:

1. date- ***dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm*** and I need to convert it to **timestamp without time zone**
2. start_time/end_tiime- ***hh:mm:ss*** and I need to convert it **time without time zone**

I need to do this in order to add them to a sql query. which looks like this:

```
sql = '''
    INSERT INTO myTable (date, start_time, end_time)
    VALUES (%s ,%s, %s, %s);'''
params = [timestamp, start_time, end_time]
self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

Comment: Do you use ORM (SQLAlchemy, Autumn, etc) or do you use some dbapi module directly, which one (psycopg2, pg8000, etc)?

Comment: I didn't try it but I think you could give `psycopg2` Python strings, floats, integers, datetime object and it will convert them by itself to compatible SQL type if not you could register an adapter. There might be complications such as different versions of postgresql treat `timestamp` with/without time zone types differently, `psycopg2` *might* expose whether postgresql compiled with integers or floats for timestamp, time. You could see what would be sent to the database by calling [`cursor.mogrify()`](http://packages.python.org/psycopg2/cursor.html#cursor.mogrify).

Comment: related: [convert timestamp without time zone returned as float by psycopg2 to datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4153025/)

Answer (score 2):

1. dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm to timestamp without time zone:

   ```
   import time

   date_string='24/10/2011 12:43'
   ttuple=time.strptime(date_string,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
   timestamp=time.mktime(ttuple)
   # 1319474580.0
   ```
2. hh:mm:ss to time without time zone:

   Can you clarify what kind of object is a `time`?

Comment: Please take a look here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: ok. thanks. If I want it as ISO 8601, without the date, just the time?

Comment: If you are given a string in `hh:mm:ss` format as input, what do you want as output?

Comment: I've tested here, this is returning a timestamp with timezone